# How do I run the AudioOutput example code on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I'm trying to run the example listed here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtmultimedia/qaudiooutput.html#details and I'm new to C++ and Qt, so I can't figure out what they mean. This is how I'm trying to implement it:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <QObject>
#include <QAudioOutput>

int main() {
    QFile sourceFile;   // class member.
    QAudioOutput* audio; // class member.
    {
        sourceFile.setFileName("C:\\Documents\\ParadigmE3-shortened.wav");
        sourceFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        QAudioFormat format;
        // Set up the format, eg.
        format.setSampleRate(8000);
        format.setChannelCount(1);
        format.setSampleSize(8);
        format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
        format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
        format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

        QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
        if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
            qWarning() << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.";
            return;
        }

        audio = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
        connect(audio, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this, SLOT(handleStateChanged(QAudio::State)));
        audio->start(&sourceFile);
    }

}
```

It's the same code as in the description, just in an `int main()` function.

I get two "invalid use of 'this' in non-member function" errors and one "return-statement with no value" error, for the lines near the end of the function. I'm sure I'm doing this wrong. I tried creating a separate function with the code and calling it from `main()`, but that resulted in errors calling the new function.

Comment: Generally the code snippets from the documentation come from the example projects supplied with QT.  Look for the whole thing, because just pasting that bit of code isn't going to work.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: QT = Quick Time...

Comment: Is this still unresolved more than one year later??

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I haven't looked at it as there wasn't any progress and it was giving me a headache. However, with what I know now about Qt I can conclude the extra error I had was likely due to Qt configuration rather than due to a mistake in the code itself. I am reluctant to approve it however. I'm not absolutely sure it will work is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the original class is within a class method where the `this` word refers to the class in question.

Here you copied the code inside the main function, and `this` lost its meaning.

You could use a smart pointer instead or simply just a stack object for the QAudioOutput, meanwhil replacing `this` with `0`. However, you would have the same issue in connect.

You could use the QCoreApplication to replace `this` with that as a parent if you had a QCoreApplication around. However, you would still have issue with the slot name because that does not seem to be defined anywhere either.

This is a slightly off-topic, but there is no point in including the whole QtWidgets here. That will slow down the compilation in general even if it does not matter that much in this case.

QFile and QDebug are not included either. The many std includes are also unnecessary. You have a "return;" statement in a function called main where you need to return an integer. That is not going to compile either.

This is the code what you could have in a very simple case.. Although it is a chopped version of the example, but it may help you to understand the mistakes:

```
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class AudioOutputTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public Q_SLOTS:
        void handleStateChanged(QAudio::State state) {
            qWarning() << "state = " << state;
            qApp->exit();
        }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile sourceFile;
    QAudioOutput* audio;

    sourceFile.setFileName("ParadigmE3-shortened.wav");
    sourceFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QAudioFormat format;
    // Set up the format, eg.
    format.setSampleRate(8000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(8);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
        qWarning() << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.";
        return 1;
    }

    audio = new QAudioOutput(format, &a);
    AudioOutputTest audioOutputTest;
    QObject::connect(audio, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), &audioOutputTest, SLOT(handleStateChanged(QAudio::State)));
    audio->start(&sourceFile);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I compiled it with the following command:

`g++ -I/usr/include/qt/QtMultimedia -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -fPIC -lQt5Core -lQt5Multimedia qtaudio.cpp`

Summary: I suggest to put that code within a class if you wanna stick to that example. That will be the easiest for you.

[Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimedia-audiooutput.html) you can find another QAudioOutput example about its proper and suggested usage.

Comment: @Jamil: include the moc. I updated the post. Please try again. Strange, it works here though. Do not worry about full path, just copy/paste the code. :-)

Comment: I see now. What is the full path of the moc?

Comment: That didn't work. It didn't find the moc. I found Qt to be exhausting and not really what I was looking for, so I gave up on it.

Comment: @JVE999: Obviously, you have to install qt and get moc in the path. That is beyond the scope of your request. It is somewhat unfair I wrote you a working code, and then you do not bother to verify, nor to select it... :/

Comment: I verified it. I installed QT. I could not find moc at all. That's rather important. It was disappointing you left at "what is the full path of the moc".

Comment: I wasn't sure how to accept the help. I gave it a 1+, but I didn't think it was responsible to accept it as a correct answer if it didn't work. Maybe if someone can confirm it would work. I've found there are easier/better ways of doing what I was trying to do and since I'm new to C++, I decided to go with them. Python can process sound, and some other C++ libraries/engines can too.